# Loud fan [PC] fan on ubuntu server

Tags: server, fan, sensors, heat

It's probably hardware thing, but i would like to know if I can do something about it.
So, i have a pc that i run as a plex/file server in my room where i sleep and live, so it's quite annoying.

*I don't mind loosing performance* because of higher temperature if the server will be quieter. (I mean as long *as i can stream my videos or access my files* i don't really care).

**Is there anything I can do about it?**

```
omichron@omichronserver:~$ inxi -Faz
System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-105-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.4.0 
           parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-105-generic root=UUID=996f3c7b-05a4-4aea-b872-e785e1a9e4d2 ro 
           maybe-ubiquity 
           Console: tty 0 dm: N/A Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: MSI model: H81M-E33 (MS-7817) v: 1.0 serial: <filter> BIOS: American Megatrends v: 6.7 
           date: 04/21/2015 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i5-4460 bits: 64 type: MCP arch: Haswell family: 6 model-id: 3C (60) 
           stepping: 3 microcode: 28 L2 cache: 6144 KiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 25598 
           Speed: 800 MHz min/max: 800/3400 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 800 2: 800 3: 800 4: 800 
           Vulnerabilities: Type: itlb_multihit status: KVM: Split huge pages 
           Type: l1tf mitigation: PTE Inversion; VMX: conditional cache flushes, SMT disabled 
           Type: mds mitigation: Clear CPU buffers; SMT disabled 
           Type: meltdown mitigation: PTI 
           Type: spec_store_bypass mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp 
           Type: spectre_v1 mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization 
           Type: spectre_v2 mitigation: Retpolines, IBPB: conditional, IBRS_FW, STIBP: disabled, RSB filling 
           Type: srbds mitigation: Microcode 
           Type: tsx_async_abort status: Not affected 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: i915 
           v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID: 8086:0412 
           Display: server: No display server data found. Headless machine? tty: 186x42 
           Message: Advanced graphics data unavailable in console. Try -G --display 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: snd_hda_intel 
           v: kernel bus ID: 00:03.0 chip ID: 8086:0c0c 
           Device-2: Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:1b.0 chip ID: 8086:8c20 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-105-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: r8169 v: kernel 
           port: e000 bus ID: 02:00.0 chip ID: 10ec:8168 
           IF: enp2s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-1: tun0 state: unknown speed: 10 Mbps duplex: full mac: N/A 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 1.20 TiB used: 90.16 GiB (7.3%) 
           SMART Message: Unable to run smartctl. Root privileges required. 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WD10EZEX-08RKKA0 size: 931.51 GiB block size: physical: 4096 B 
           logical: 512 B speed: 3.0 Gb/s serial: <filter> rev: 0A80 
           ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Western Digital model: WD3200AAJS-56B4A0 size: 298.09 GiB block size: physical: 512 B 
           logical: 512 B speed: 3.0 Gb/s serial: <filter> rev: 3A01 scheme: GPT 
Partition: ID-1: / raw size: 298.09 GiB size: 292.41 GiB (98.09%) used: 19.39 GiB (6.6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdb2 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 33.0 C mobo: 49.0 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 1102 fan-1: 0 fan-3: 0 fan-4: 0 fan-5: 0 
           Voltages: 12v: N/A 5v: N/A 3.3v: 3.44 vbat: 3.36 
Info:      Processes: 163 Uptime: 24m Memory: 7.65 GiB used: 620.8 MiB (7.9%) Init: systemd v: 245 runlevel: 5 Compilers: 
           gcc: N/A Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 running in: tty 0 (SSH) inxi: 3.0.38
```

-- random text to split tow code sample --

```
omichron@omichronserver:~$ sensors
nct6779-isa-0a00
Adapter: ISA adapter
Vcore:                 880.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +1.74 V)
in1:                     0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)
AVCC:                    3.44 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
+3.3V:                   3.44 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
in4:                     0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)
in5:                     0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)
in6:                   232.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
3VSB:                    3.39 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
Vbat:                    3.36 V  (min =  +2.70 V, max =  +3.63 V)
in9:                     1.02 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in10:                  144.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in11:                  120.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in12:                    1.02 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in13:                    1.10 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in14:                  152.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
fan1:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:                  1100 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan4:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan5:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
SYSTIN:                 +49.0°C  (high =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)  sensor = thermal diode
CPUTIN:                +127.5°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = CPU diode
AUXTIN0:                +36.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN1:               +118.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN2:               +111.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN3:                +31.0°C    sensor = thermal diode
SMBUSMASTER 0:           +0.0°C  (high =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)
PECI Agent 0:           +32.0°C  
PCH_CHIP_CPU_MAX_TEMP:   +0.0°C  
PCH_CHIP_TEMP:           +0.0°C  
intrusion0:            OK
intrusion1:            ALARM
beep_enable:           disabled

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +32.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +32.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +29.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +28.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +29.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

Comment: Check [this](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=62d5f97548) out. Investigate if you need an additional driver to find more than one fan.  (Inxi recognized one). Otherwise you need to replace your fan - my two fans run at 500 rpm and are absolutely silent. Make sure you've got a 4 connector fan for speed control

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand this page, what driver should i looking for? Board? Or i should check the output of my system and the given example?

Comment: Nevermind, can you check if your bios/UEFI is able to control the fan? At a second glimpse there won't be any software controlling your fan.

Comment: Postscript: I'd check the temp of CPUTIN and AUXTIN: They are above 100°C !

Comment: It dosent seems like i can control the fan in the bios, but i will look after it.

Comment: What does that mean? I see that they are really high. It means the cpu has hardware faliure? 
Edit: Ive read about it and they say if its that high my pc would have been burnt down, so probably they are faulty values.

Comment: did you run `pwmconfig`?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about AUXIN* temps, especially if you don't have any extra thermistors attached.  Even with mine attached they never read right in Ubuntu.  I'm not sure why CPUTIN is that high either, given coretemp is saying 32C.

Comment: Yeah, i ran. I didnt hear/saw that the fan is stopped.